# Composer could not find package when using inline alias

Tags: composer-php

According to https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/aliases.md#require-inline-alias I'm trying to use aliasing for patching something using a cloned repo. For testing I need to require the patch branch (called deps in this case) from that repo.

However composer fails:

```
composer require -vvv php-pm/httpkernel-adapter@dev-deps

   [InvalidArgumentException]
   Could not find package php-pm/httpkernel-adapter@dev-deps at any version for your minimum-stability (dev). Check the package spelling or your minimum-stability
```

The alias in my `composer.json` looks like this:

```
...
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/andig/php-pm-httpkernel"
    }
]
```

The `andig/php-pm-httpkernel` repo is a clone and has the `deps` branch.

Why isn't composer able to require the package from aliased repo in the desirec branch?

Answer (score 0):

This is embarassing. On the command line it needs to be

```
composer require -vvv php-pm/httpkernel-adapter:dev-deps
```

Notice the `:` instead of `@`.